# problem does not follow DCP rule when trying to create a constraint for positive semidefinite cone constraint

Tags: cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to code a method in a research paper where I have to solve a SDP. Where one of the constraint is S succeed or equal to s*s^T. Where S is a NXN matrix and s is NX1 matrix. s^T is transpose of s.

I have found that for semidefinite constraint, Both sides of a postive semidefinite cone constraint must be square matrices and affine. Here both S and s are unknown we are minimizing equation based on S and s. and S curvature is showing unknown.

```py
n = 2
np.random.seed(1)
Q = np.random.randn(n, n)
b = np.random.randn(n,1)

S = cp.Variable((n,n))
s = cp.Variable((n,1))

objective = cp.Minimize(cp.trace(Q@S) + 2*b.transpose()@s)
constraints = [cp.trace(S) - one.transpose()@s <= 0, S >> s@s.T]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

print("Optimal value", prob.solve())
print("Optimal status", prob.status)
print(s.value) # A numpy ndarray.
```

**This is the ERROR that I am getting**

```
  File "/home/mtech0/18CS60R64/cvxpy/SDP_test.py", line 45, in <module>
    print("Optimal value", prob.solve())

  File "/home/mtech0/18CS60R64/anaconda3/envs/mtp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 289, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/mtech0/18CS60R64/anaconda3/envs/mtp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 567, in _solve
    self._construct_chains(solver=solver, gp=gp)

  File "/home/mtech0/18CS60R64/anaconda3/envs/mtp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 510, in _construct_chains
    raise e

  File "/home/mtech0/18CS60R64/anaconda3/envs/mtp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 499, in _construct_chains
    construct_intermediate_chain(self, candidate_solvers, gp=gp)

  File "/home/mtech0/18CS60R64/anaconda3/envs/mtp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/reductions/solvers/intermediate_chain.py", line 56, in construct_intermediate_chain
    raise DCPError("Problem does not follow DCP rules." + append)

DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules.
```

Comment: Transform `S >> ... ` into an LMI using the Schur complement. Also, I believe this question should be at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think it is already an LMI. Isn't it?

Comment: If `s` is an optimization variable, then `s * s.T` is quadratic in `s`. That which is quadratic cannot be linear.

Comment: Use `bmat` to build the block matrix. As an example, take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2776808/339790).